# :app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug' Error

Tags: java, android, kotlin

**What is causing the problem?**
I am encountering such an error in my application sale. I couldn't find anything exactly as a solution.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.core:core-ktx:+.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Skipped due to earlier error
      > Failed to list versions for androidx.core:core-ktx.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap/androidx/core/core-ktx/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap/androidx/core/core-ktx/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap/androidx/core/core-ktx/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Narendra_Nath said, it is because of the bintray dependencies and Jcenter shutting down.
you can refer to this article   https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown

the solution that worked for me is changing the repositories in the (Top-level build.gradle) to

```
    buildscript {
      repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
        url "https://repo.spring.io/release"
        }
        maven {
        url "https://repository.jboss.org/maven2"
      } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your dependency correctly  `"androidx.core:core-ktx:$core_version"`

Comment: Could not HEAD 'https://dl.bintray.com/crysis21/Android/com/github/QuadFlask/colorpicker/0.0.15/colorpicker-0.0.15.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

Answer (score 0):

This is because bintray support is now no longer there.
Go to your project level `build.gradle` and comment out the
bintray dependencies in the `allprojects` and `repositories` section

[Bintray Shutdown](https://testfairy.com/blog/jcenter-and-bintray-is-shutting-down-what-to-do/)

Comment: Could not HEAD 'https://dl.bintray.com/crysis21/Android/com/github/QuadFlask/colorpicker/0.0.15/colorpicker-0.0.15.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

Comment: Comment those two lines from your build.gradle  and add jcenter() and mavenCentral() in those blocks if they arent there already